# Property 'token' does not exist on type 'Object' - Angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, angular8, mean-stack

> I am watching MEAN Stack - Mean Auth App Tutorial in Angular 2, since I am new to Angular and
> I'm using Angular 8, some of the codes is deprecated due to the new
> updates. So I have this code and I don't know how to fix it.
>
> This is my working code in Auth.service.ts
>
> There are no errors in this codes

```
    authenticateUser(user){
    let headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.append('Content-Type','application/json');
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users/authenticate', user,{headers: headers})
  }

  storeUserData(token, user){
    localStorage.setItem('id_token', token);
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    this.authToken = token;
    this.user = user;
  }

  logout(){
    this.authToken = null;
    this.user = null;
    localStorage.clear();
  }
```

> In my login.component.ts, there's an error showing
>
> **Property 'token' does not exist on type 'Object**
>
> **Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Object**
>
> **Property 'msg' does not exist on type 'Object**

> This is my login.component.ts code

```
onLoginSubmit(){
    const user = {
      username: this.username,
      password: this.password
    }

    this.authService.authenticateUser(user).subscribe(data => {
      if(data){
        this.authService.storeUserData(data.token, data.user);
        this.flashMessage.show('You are now logged in', {
          cssClass: 'alert-success',
          timeout: 5000});
        this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
      } else {
        this.flashMessage.show(data.msg, {
          cssClass: 'alert-danger',
          timeout: 5000});
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
      }
    });
  }
```

> login.components.ts file If I put wrong login credentials, It's
> logging in.

```
 onLoginSubmit(){
    const user = {
      username: this.username,
      password: this.password
    }

    this.authService.authenticateUser(user).subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
      if(user){
        this.authService.storeUserData(data.token, data.user);
        this.flashMessage.show('You are now logged in', {
          cssClass: 'alert-success',
          timeout: 5000});
        this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
      } else {
        this.flashMessage.show(data.msg, {
          cssClass: 'alert-danger',
          timeout: 5000});
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: Can you put the console.log(data) just before the if(data). and also paste the response here. it will be easy to give answer.

Comment: what do u see in console.log(data);

Comment: {success: false, msg: "User not found"}
msg: "User not found"
success: false

Comment: I enter wrong username and password but, in my Interface it is "Login Successfully"

Comment: there must be a single error on one time submit.

Comment: Property 'token' does not exist on type 'Object
Property 'user' does not exist on type 'Object
Property 'msg' does not exist on type 'Object

Comment: this is my only problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are talking about typescript error: `http.post` returns an `Observable<object>`, so `data` is an `object`, and there is no property `token`, `user`, `msg` in object.

With the information you told us, your `authenticate` WS should return:

```js
interface SuccessResponse {
  token: string;
  user: any; // should change any to your user type
}

interface FailureResponse {
  success: false;
  msg: string;
}

type AuthResponse = SuccessResponse | FailureResponse;

authenticateUser(user): Observable<AuthResponse> {
    // header for content-type is not needed
    return this.http.post<AuthResponse>('http://localhost:3000/users/authenticate', user);
}
```

You can use it like it:

```js
 onLoginSubmit() {
    const user = {
      username: this.username,
      password: this.password
    }

    this.authService.authenticateUser(user).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(data);
      if ('token' in response) {
        // response is SuccessResponse
        this.authService.storeUserData(response.token, response.user);
        this.flashMessage.show('You are now logged in', {
          cssClass: 'alert-success',
          timeout: 5000});
        this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
      } else {
        // response is FailureResponse
        this.flashMessage.show(response.msg, {
          cssClass: 'alert-danger',
          timeout: 5000});
        this.router.navigate(['login']);
      }
    });
  }
```

That should work for you. However, the standard is that you should return an error (e.g code 401) when login failed, not an OK status (200) with `success: false`. The code will be different in this case

Comment: It worked, thanks mate, perhaps you can help me with my validation. when I put wrong username and password, it's logging in

Comment: I updated the codes above, I hope you can help me with it. thanks

Comment: Can you update your post with `data` log when login is successful?